# How to instantiate multiple nested non-static inner classes - java

Tags: java, inner-classes, non-static

I have the following piece of code:

```
public class InnerClassStuff {
   public class A{
       public class AA{}
    }
}
```

my question is how can I instantitae an AA object?

I've tried the following but it won't compile:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   InnerClassStuff object = new InnerClassStuff();
   A a = object.new A();
   AA aa = object.a.new AA(); //error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. So, you can't declare `A a= ..`, you need wrapped it with outer class like below:

```
InnerClassStuff object = new InnerClassStuff();
InnerClassStuff.A.AA a = object.new A().new AA();
```

Or,

```
InnerClassStuff object = new InnerClassStuff();
InnerClassStuff.A a = object.new A();
InnerClassStuff.A.AA aa = a.new AA();
```

Comment: Or replace the last line of the original code with `AA aa = a.new AA();`

Comment: I tried using  AA aa = a.new AA(); but it gave me an error saying "AA cannot be resolved to a type". I am using eclipse by the way.

Comment: @JerryJia, You can't directly use Inner class. You should wrapped it with outer class.

Answer (score 0):

To access the class you have to use The outer class name, only by doing so you can have reference variable of inner class. eg:

```
InnerClassStuff object = new InnerClassStuff();
InnerClassStuff.A a = object.new A();
InnerClassStuff.A.AA aa = a.new AA();
```